# Grails: getClass().getResource("whatever") doesn't work

Tags: grails, resources, classpath

How do I load a file with getResource(String) in Grails?

Class and file Location:

```
- grails-app
  - utils
    - MyClass.groovy
    - myfile.jks
```

With the following I get `null`

```
MyClass.class.getResource('myfile.jks')
MyClass.class.getResource('/myfile.jks')
MyClass.class.getResource('/grails-app/utils/myfile.jks')
MyClass.class.getResource('/utils/myfile.jks')
```

Answer (score 4):

I would generally throw files like that in the `grails-app/conf` directory which is on the classpath.  Then You should be able to use `MyClass.class.getResource('/myfile.jks')`.

Comment: Adding to conf folder works. You might have to restart the server.

Answer (score 0):

You need to get your resource file onto the classpath. One quick way to do this is to place it in the src/java directory in your project.